# School plant identification and care

Tags: identification, plant-care

At my school, every project team has their own plant and needs to take care of it. I was wondering if you guys could help me out taking care of my plant.

A picture of my plant can be seen below.

So, by that, I have a couple of questions:

- What's the name of this plant?
- What is the best way to take care of this plant?

[image: School project team plant]

Comment: That's a bit better - tell me, if you pick a leaf, is it quite stiff and has a scent if you break it (I think this is Bay laurel, or Laurus nobilis)? It looks like its got a problem of some sort already, judging by the yellowing/browning of leaves, so how long have you had it?  Did they tell you whether to keep it outdoors or inside? What part of the world are you in?

Comment: @Bamboo When I pick a leaf it is quite stiff indeed. It doesn't seem to have any scent when breaking it. We've had it for quite some time already (like 6 months) and give it water every 2 days or so.. We keep it indoors and live in The Netherlands. Thanks for helping us out!